# Select a cell in row based on today's matching month & year in column A

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here's the sheet

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 2023 |  | 5 |
| Feb 2023 |  | 10 |
| Mar 2023 |  | 15 |
| Apr 2023 |  | 20 |
| May 2023 |  | 25 |
| Jun 2023 |  | 30 |
| Jul 2023 |  | 35 |
| Aug 2023 |  | 40 |

Todays date is in April 2023

I'm trying to make a query that grabs the number in column C when column A matches TODAY.

Here's what I attempted:

```
=QUERY(A1:C8,"select C where A = date '"&TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)
```

but this returns 5 (which is the first row) when I'm expecting 20. How can I modify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=QUERY(A1:C8,"select C where A = date '"&TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)
```

OR

```
=filter(C:C,eomonth(A:A,)=eomonth(today(),))
```

[image]